# Simulate deadlock in Java + Spring + JPA?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

Is it possible to get a DB deadlock exception with Spring + JPA Repositories + H2/PostgreSQL?

I've found several examples of how to simulate a deadlock with raw SQL ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22775150/5028874), [two](http://postgresql.freeideas.cz/simulate-deadlock-postgresql/), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825147/how-to-simulate-deadlock-on-sql-server), [four](http://bighow.org/questions/22775150/how-to-simulate-deadlock-in-postgresql-)), but my goal is to do the same in a more high-level environment.

I did some experiments with concurerent threads, `CrudRepository.save(entity)`, and `Thread.sleep()` but to no avail (I guess it's not possible). What else can I try?

Comment: Sure, entityManager has a lock method, you should be able to do pessimistic locking and cause a deadlock.

Comment: Well, I achieved some results with 2 instances of entityManager (and no Threads at all). But before I share the code, I'd like to make sure whether I actually run into deadlock.. So, now my application freezes after commiting the last SQL query, and it actually looks like the deadlock, but I don't see any exceptions/error messages like "deadlock detected" in console. It is okay? I tried both with H2 and PostgreSQL.